# Sencha CMD Error "Did not locate framework package"

Tags: extjs, sencha-cmd

I'm new to Sencha and I just installed Sencha CMD. Following Sencha's [instructions](http://docs.sencha.com/cmd/5.x/extjs/cmd_app.html) I type the following on the command line:

```
sencha generate app -ext MyApp ./app
```

But all I get is this error message:

```
C:\SenchaCMD\Sencha>sencha generate app -ext MyApp ./app
Sencha Cmd v5.0.1.231
[WRN] Did not locate framework package
[ERR] java.lang.NullPointerException
     at com.sencha.util.PathUtil.normalizePathCharacters
     ...
     ...
     at com.sencha.command.Sencha.main(Sencha.java:141)
```

I've searched the internet for the error message and haven't found anything.

Answer (score 2):

Try below command to generate sencha app.

`sencha -sdk F:/touch-2.3.0 generate app Test-app .`(Dot represent current directory)

sdk is the path to your touch library.

Test-app is your app name.

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same problem.

I had installed Sencha Cmd in a non-standard folder (within `C:\Program Files (x86)\`). Uninstalling Sencha Cmd and reinstalling it in the default folder (`C:\Users\<UserName>\bin\`) made the error go away.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to comment directly on the other answers so here goes:

Comment: @Code_Cracker: When I experienced the exact same error codes as boggdan, I also tried your proposed solution, and some variations of it. I downloaded ExtJS and tried referencing it in various ways, placing it in different directories (with and without long paths containing spaces etc.). Nothing that I tried worked, except uninstalling Sencha CMD and installing it in the default location.

Comment: @code4jhon: I also tried uninstalling and reinstalling Java. Playing around with different versions (latest version, the slightly older version suggested by Sencha, 32-bit and 62-bit versions etc.). Actually, both Ruby and Java was in place and their locations added to the system Path variable. The only thing wrong was where I had elected to install Sencha CMD. Obviously, Sencha CMD does NOT like to be installed in the Program Files folder.

Answer (score 1):

You need to run it with the ExtJS sdk path.
In my case, the just downloaded ExtJS sdk:

```
sencha -sdk "C:\Users\username\Downloads\ext-5.1.1-trial\ext-5.1.1" generate app -ext MyApp ./app
```

It also need administrators right if you installed it in the ProgramFile Folder.
Run your console with administator rights.

Answer (score 0):

**"Did not locate framework package"**

You should run this command from inside of touch-2.3.1 folder.

**[ERR] java.lang.NullPointerException**

run java -version looks like you are missing java

Answer (score 0):

...and as a linux user, the same error appears if you install sencha command via sudo. You shouldn't do that.

so just run

```
guy@idoru:~$ chmod +x SenchaCmd-<version>-linux-x64.run
guy@idoru:~$ ./SenchaCmd-<version>-linux-x64.run
```

instead of

```
guy@idoru:~$ sudo ./SenchaCmd-<version>-linux-x64.run
```